# Invert 1 bit in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I have 1 bit in a `byte` (always in the lowest order position) that I'd like to invert.
ie given 00000001 I'd like to get 00000000 and with 00000000 I'd like 00000001.

I solved it like this:

```
bit > 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

I'm curious to see how else it could be done.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

How about:

```
bit ^= 1;
```

This simply XOR's the first bit with 1, which toggles it.

If you want to flip bit #N, counting from 0 on the right towards 7 on the left (for a byte), you can use this expression:

```
bit ^= (1 << N);
```

This won't disturb any other bits, but if the value is only ever going to be 0 or 1 in decimal value (ie. all other bits are 0), then the following can be used as well:

```
bit = 1 - bit;
```

Again, if there is only going to be one bit set, you can use the same value for 1 as in the first to flip bit #N:

```
bit = (1 << N) - bit;
```

Of course, at that point you're not actually doing bit-manipulation in the same sense.

The expression you have is fine as well, but again will manipulate the entire value.

Also, if you had expressed a single bit as a `bool` value, you could do this:

```
bit = !bit;
```

Which toggles the value.

---

**More of a joke**:
Of course, the "enterprisey" way would be to use a lookup table:

```
byte[] bitTranslations = new byte[256];
bitTranslations[0] = 1;
bitTranslations[1] = 0;

bit = bitTranslations[bit];
```

Comment: This has the advantage of not requiring the first bit to be selected first, as well.

Comment: I first wanted to use ! but then discovered it's only for bools. Fun stuff, working at this level.

Comment: I'd second the 'expressing it as a bool' argument - depending on what you are doing, may make the code a little easier to read for the next guy to maintain.

Comment: if I use bool then I have to cast it all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution isn't correct because if bit == 2 (10) then your assignment will yield bit == 0 (00).

This is what you want:

```
bit ^= 1;
```

Comment: You're right, but I've already shifted the bit to the lowest order so this isn't a problem for me

Comment: If all you're trying to do is test/manipulate that one bit you can get rid of the shift operation and just xor it in-place with a different constant (e.g. if it was the 7th most significant bit you do something like bit ^= 0x40;)