# Flip the binary

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

I want to flip the binary to `1` or `0`. For example I have the binary `101` the output should be `010`. I've been trying to iterate through the array and change the value but the output is always `0, 000, 0000, 00`.

HERE is the code i'm working with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Input Binary: ");
        String x = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] bin = x.ToCharArray();
        int[] nbin =  new int[bin.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < bin.Length; i ++)
        {

            int a = bin[i];
            if(a == 0)
            {

                nbin.SetValue(1, i);

            }
            if(a == 1)
            {

                nbin.SetValue(0, i);
            }

        }

        foreach (var e in nbin)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Doen't the `~` operator just invert the bits?

Comment: This might be a case of 0 != '0'? The character values for 0 and 1 (your input) are not the numeric values 0 and 1

Comment: Try step by step debugging (F11), and see that a doesn't contain what you think it is.

Comment: Following post lines up a bunch of different approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605913/invert-1-bit-in-c-sharp#2605915

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing integers with characters, which would probably never get you the expected result because you are comparing with the character's ASCII value.

Characters are represented by `''` in C#, so you should add them to the 0s and 1s in the condition:

```
if(a == '0')
{

    nbin.SetValue(1, i);

}
if(a == '1')
{

    nbin.SetValue(0, i);
}
```

You can also print an error message if the user enters something weird:

```
if(a == '0')
{

    nbin.SetValue(1, i);

} else if(a == '1')
{

    nbin.SetValue(0, i);
} else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input Invalid!");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not working with *characters in the string* without arrays?

```
  String x = "101";

  String result = string.Concat(x.Select(c => c == '0' ? '1' : '0'));

  // 010
  Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the data in as a String, and then turn it into a `char` array. A `char` represents the codepoint for a given character. the *character* `0` has the codepoint 48, or just `'0'` if you use a `char` literal, but not the *number* 0.

You should compare to the character:

```
if(a == '0')
```

Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)